# Angular observables and how to iterate through an array of object to collect fields into an array

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to iterate through my array of objects and add specific fields in to their own array for which I can possibly use for list boxes and other front end stuff.

I am trying to iterate through this object and put objects 'appSupportedId' into its own array for instance I would want it to look like

array of appsSupported = [5,6,15,etc]

I am trying to do this with my http get service and using RXJS observables to do so. Any suggestions would be appreciated on how to get this to happen, thanks.

**JSON Object**

```
    [
{
    "applicationUserSubscriptionUniqueId": 18639,
    "createdByName": "2222",
    "updatedDate": "2019-12-02T19:17:45.000+0000",
    "applicationsSupported": {
        "appSupportedId": 5,
        "supportAreaId": 123,
        "supportAreas": {
            "applicationId": 123,
        },
        "appSupportedName": "app1"
    },
    "userSubscriptionInformation": {
        "userSubscribedUniqueId": 18638,
    },
    "reportSubscriptionId": 18638,

 },
 {
    "applicationUserSubscriptionUniqueId": 18638,
    "createdByName": "2222",
    "updatedDate": "2019-12-02T19:17:45.000+0000",
    "applicationsSupported": {
        "appSupportedId": 6,
        "supportAreaId": 123,
        "supportAreas": {
            "applicationId": 123,
        },
        "appSupportedName": "app2"
    },
    "userSubscriptionInformation": {
        "userSubscribedUniqueId": 18638,
    },
    "reportSubscriptionId": 18638,

},
{
    "applicationUserSubscriptionUniqueId": 18637,
    "createdByName": "2222",
    "updatedDate": "2019-12-02T19:17:45.000+0000",
    "applicationsSupported": {
        "appSupportedId": 15,
        "supportAreaId": 123,
        "supportAreas": {
            "applicationId": 123,
        },
        "appSupportedName": "app3"
    },
    "userSubscriptionInformation": {
        "userSubscribedUniqueId": 18638,
    },
    "reportSubscriptionId": 18638,

},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using **flatMap**:

```
appsSupported = [];

constructor() {
  this.appsSupported = (this.data.flatMap(x => x.applicationsSupported)).map(y=> y.appSupportedId)
}
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwbyxx?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: but this object is coming from a HTTP GET service which is coming through as an Observable and I cannot just assign it to an array like the demo suggests

Comment: Why not? After subscribe, add, this.data = resp;and then add this code I shared

Comment: excuse my ignorance....i may need more guidence...like this?  this.appUserSubService.getSpecificUser(this.userId)
        .subscribe(info =>
          this.appsSupported = (info.flatMap(x => x.applicationsSupported)).map(y=> y.appSupportedId)
          
        )
        console.log(this.appsSupported)

Answer (score 1):

Just use rxjs map with array with

```
const supportedAppIds$ = this.http.get<YourType[]>(YOURPATH).pipe(
    map((data: YourType[]) => data.map(entry => entry.applicationsSupported.appSupportedId))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the rxjs map operator, see my example.

```js
const supportedApps$ = this.http.get('http://example.com').pipe(
    map((el: MyAppData) => el.applicationsSupported.appSupportedId)
);
```

Then subscribe to `supportedApps$`, for example in your template.